"errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Named export 'post' not found. The requested module 'axios' is a CommonJS module which maynot support all module.exports
Updated NodeJs version from 16.x to 20.x and changed commonjs module to ES Module but resulted in this error. Added Type Module in Package.json
const axios = require('axios'); -\> import axios from 'axios';

and
export async function InvokeRestService(url, data) {
    try {
        return  await axios.post(url, data);
    } catch (err) {
        handleError(url, err, 'InvokeRestService');
    }
 }

and tried
import axios,{ Post } from 'axios'; 

and
export async function InvokeRestService(url, data) {
    try {
        return  await post(url, data);
    } catch (err) {
        handleError(url, err, 'InvokeRestService');
    }
 }

but still throws ERROR:Uncaught Exception

SyntaxError: Named export 'post' not found. The requested module 'axios' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.\nCommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:\n\nimport pkg from 'axios';\nconst { post } = pkg;\n



The error means means what it says, you can't import post because there's no such export. The question lacks clear problem statement, it's unclear what's wrong with import axios from 'axios'
